Upcoming Events: Yom Hashoah
I see that the upcoming events sidebar seems to believe Yom Hashoah is occurring today (May 5th, 27th Nissan).
The actual date of observance in Israel this year is 28th Nissan (so starting at sunset on May 5th) - it is pushed off by a day to prevent any chillul shabbat in preparing for the day's events.
Is the upcoming events sidebar still updated manually? Maybe a mod would like to edit?

The references to 27th Iyar and 28th Iyar should be 27th Nissan and 28th Nissan

@EdwardB You are correct

Yes, these are put in manually. My mistake. I've fixed it. Thanks!
Note that the start and end times for these "events" won't necessarily track their precise start and end times, but rather, roughly, the start and end of the span when the moderator putting in the notice feels it could be timely to users somewhere in the world. Don't expect too much rigor on this point. That said, ending a day early is certainly a mistake.
